# whenever i render my model, my GPU instantly goes to maximum usage

Tags: rendering

blender noob here. I have just finished my first model in blender. all I have to do is render it. but whenever I render it is all pixelated and distorted, this massively intensifies whenever I move the UI camera. I went to the task manager and my  3d graphics card is at maximum capacity. I have a powerful one too. I have tried the entire very little amount of things I can do and it just wouldn't work. pls help

and thank you

HELP WANTED

Comment: The pixelation is called noise. Until unless your scene is denoised, you will see noise whether how high the samples. I think you sould watch some blender tutorials and learn more about gpus. It is normally ok for your gpu to max out at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a small amount of samples (like 128) and there is not to much lighting. In that case, if you have the denoiser is going to look weird. Also, maybe you are using both the GPU and CPU, I have bad results when I do that (I asume that there is a way of doing it properly). Try to increase the number of samples, change between CPU and GPU and see if something change...
And some pictures of your problem can help!
Good luck